# Event members only for 3 days then open to the public

Tags: civievent, civimail

I have a need to be able to enter a period when an event opens for registration/access to a file to members only for a period of time (normally 3 days).
So the goal, to be clear, is to open an event for registration to members only for 3 days, then open to the general public.
Ideally, if those open dates were also available to civiMail as a token - but that might be asking a bit much.  I'm prepared to write an extension to make this happen but if someone has something similar, then I can build on that too.

Comment: Which CMS are you using?

Comment: Wordpress 4.9.8 and CiviCRM 5.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

There are methods to do members-only events on this Stack Exchange question: [Is it possible to restrict event registration to members?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10937/is-it-possible-to-restrict-event-registration-to-members)

Since you're willing to write an extension, it's probably a good use of your time to start with the [Members Only Event](https://github.com/MillerTech-CRM/uk.co.nfpservices.module.memberonlyevent) extension and add the ability to automatically open the event to the public after a certain date, which would be added to the custom fields that the extension creates.  Please don't forget to submit a pull request with your feature to the author!

Comment: Interesting - to be clear, I am not talking about registration for an event, but rather viewing and accessing information about an event.  We publish events for our registered folks with an exclusion period for members only, then open it to public.  The host manages registration.  So it's an interesting issue to work through - should be fun? :)

Comment: The Question has the phrase "when an event opens for registration" but here you say you are "not talking about registration". Does the Q need clarifying?

Comment: I found this issue tonight, which seems related and may be worth tracking/coordinating: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/39