# Roles for specific event registration

Tags: civievent

I have 10 events that i only want authenticated users to be able to register for. I also have one event that anyone(unauthenticated user) should be able to register for. Drupal Permissions are forcing me to choose one way or the other (authenticated user or unauthenticated user). Because of duplicates i am only wanting one event to be opened for unauthenticated users to register?

Answer (score 3):

There's an extension for a very similar scenario: [Member Only Event](https://civicrm.org/extensions/member-only-event).  If your authenticated members have memberships this will do the trick.  There are similar options here: [Is it possible to restrict event registration to members?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/10937/12)  Ultimately, if none of these meet your needs a small extension might be in order.

One other option is to use [Webform CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) integration to make either your authenticated events (or more likely, the single unauthenticated event) a webform, which you can then restrict access to separately from your other event signup pages.